# How to load html files with jquery load() and zend framework?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework, load

i have a jquery ajax function, something like:

```
$(".content").load("test-content.phtml", function() {
    //some logic
});
```

and my zend framework module:

```
content
    - controllers
        - TestController.php
            - public function testContentAction(){}
    - views
        - scripts
            - test
               - test-content.phtml
```

My question is how to tell the `load()` function where the `test-content.phtml` is to load content from it.

do i have to call the `content/test/test-content` function from my controller ?

Also, i know that there is a `AjaxContext` helper in the framework but i need to load this file using ajax.

any ideas how to go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That .phtml file should be rendered by a controller, then your load function should take the action url as a parameter.

```
$(".content").load("url/to/controllerAction");
```

Comment: isn't the phtml file rendered by the controller by default?

Comment: It should be. You can check the request response using Firebug just to make sure that the response has the html you need inside it.

Comment: i think i managed to load the file. in the controller action i have a css file (`$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet...`) ... that one doesn't seem to lead. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to render the view without layout since it's just a piece of HTML appended to your page's DOM. At the same time any CSS file declared in your action won't be applied. You simply need to put your CSS rules in one of the CSS files which is loaded in the page in which you append the HTML to.